# How can I trigger a Windows build of my CRAN package for an older R version?

Tags: r, cran

One of my R packages ([pkgfilecache](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=pkgfilecache)) on CRAN is not available for R 3.4 under Windows, and I would like to change that.

The package [passed all CRAN checks](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_pkgfilecache.html) and seems to work under Windows with R 3.4. (I do not have a Windows machine, but I think so because the package [passes all unit tests on Appveyor for that platform and R version](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/dfsp-spirit/pkgfilecache)). But apparently it was simply not built/published for Windows and R 3.4 by CRAN.

My questions are:

1. Is there any way for me to trigger a Windows build for that version on CRAN, so that my package becomes available?
2. How can I find out *why* it was not built?

Comment: No. CRAN supplies windows binaries for r-devel, r-release (currently R 4.0.2), and r-oldrel (the last patch of the previous minor version, i.e., R 3.6.3). That's it. You'll need to create your own repository if you want to supply binaries for older R versions (why? If someone insists on using ancient versions, they should install Rtools and install from source).

Comment: @Roland Thanks for the information. Would you add that as an answer (with a reference if possible) so that I can accept it? I guess the answer to my 2nd question is then 'because it was published too late to be built for that R version'.